# Using fonts for specific Dynamic Type sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Replacing app-wide fonts for Bold/Semibold/Regular is easy enough using *appearance* proxy but is there a way to check for the dynamic text size used (if one was set) ?

E.g:

> Label1: Style used .body / Current font SF
>
> Label2: Style used .title1 / Current font SF

Expected:

> Replace font for "body" style (app-wide) to Font1
>
> Replace font for "title1" style (app-wide) to Font2

Possible solution:

> Compare fonts before setting a new one ? (Using FontDescriptors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent article by Curt Clifton: http://curtclifton.net/appearance-manager using a protocol based approach. Another way could be using the appearance proxy.